# email authentications

Tags: iphone

hey can any one suggest me is there any API or example for authenticating email addresses in iphone app

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regular expression to check email validation.

You can do a simple test:

`NSString *emailRegEx =
    @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%\&'*+/=?\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";`

NSPredicate *regExPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

BOOL myStringMatchesRegEx = [regExPredicate evaluateWithObject:myString];

The only question that remains is: what is a regular expression that can be used to verify that an NSString contains a syntactically valid email address?

Comment: not validating the email authenticating mails like gmail,hotmail etc.

Comment: this is not exactly what i want, me want  to validate real mail ids and
passwords of messengers

Comment: Do u mean checking it from server? If this, you need to send an HTTP request to server. For that there is no API present in iPhone. u need to write code.

Comment: thanx for the info can you suggest me any example or  post some code for this waiting for response

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

NSString * xmlString = @"Hello";
NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.company.com/myservice"];
NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse * serviceResponse;
NSError * serviceError;
serviceResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];

Comment: thanx mate i got Auth key and i need to use it for login how can i do that work please post some code or suggest any url or example